# Referer not setting properly in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview, http-headers

So I have a webapp running through an Android WebView and I need to properly use `document.referrer` in the JavaScript on my webpages. I've tried the following:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Referer", view.getUrl());
        view.loadUrl(url, headers);
        return false;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to get passed correctly. I set a breakpoint inside, checked the headers variable, and the url is correct, but the value for `document.referrer` called from the JavaScript on the next page doesn't match what I'd set it to.

Comment: did u get a solution for it? I am not getting the Referer header as well in my webview url

Comment: I'm sorry to say I didn't.

Comment: Any solutions for this? As I've read in the android documentation, they always overwrite `Referer` with the `baseUrl` setting, but I cannot overwrite the frakin referer (nor the `baseUrl`) >_<

Comment: @elboletaire Unfortunately not. It's been a long time since I ran into this. If you do find a solution though, be sure to come back with the answer for posterity!